# want to increase width of whole calendar by ng boostrap datepicker

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I want to make this range selector calendar more wider as well as i want to custom this using css . please anyone help me out.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBhio.png)

Comment: Find the class name from the developer's tool and try to modify it accordingly using `::ng-deep`

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example of what you have at the moment so that I can work on it further?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qmwqne?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hi Naman, please check this.

Comment: I guess you created the wrong example. Please check your `app.module.ts`. I think by mistake you copied `app.component.ts` code there.

Comment: sorry, i have changed now. but unable to install "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" in stackblitz

Comment: Customizing this is kind of difficult. I will give it a try.